# Help with Macroeconomics Question: IS-LM Model

Tags: macroeconomics, aggregate-production, aggregate-demand, interest, model

I know this is supposed to be a simple question, but I need to check the answers for it and as it was a past exam question I do not have the results for it.If anyone can help out, that would be wonderful!!

The Question is the the following:

Closed Economy given:

C = 40 + 0.5Yd. I = 0.4Y-10i, G = 12.5, T = 5, Yd = Y - T and i = 2.5 + 0.5Y

(a) Find IS curve equation (b) Find Y equilibrium (c) find i equilibrium

Comment: What did you tried? On this site we require self-study questions to post their attempt at solution for self study. Tell us what did you tried to do to answer a b and c, otherwise the question will be closed by the rules of the site